# Undelete records in Microsoft Access

Tags: windows, data-recovery, microsoft-access

About 600 records in a Microsoft Access File (.mdb) have been deleted. The .mdb file size hasn't changed, being around 20 MB.

*AccessFIX* (Demo) shows the exact number and contents of the deleted records in its own viewer. Unfortunately the full version (which would undelete/save the records) costs around 180€.

Is there any free way to undelete deleted records?

I have already tried, with no luck in properly (if ever) undeleting the records:

- Recovery Data Access
- Stellar Phoenix Access Recovery
- Mdb Recovery
- SysTools Access Recovery
- Advanced Access Repair
- Advanced Office Repair

Comment: Replace the database file from a backup media.

Comment: Does the database have a table where deleted data is moved to in the event it needs to be recovered?

Comment: @Ramhound obviously, no backup was taken before adding those 600 records.
CharlieRB: unfortunately, not. As far as I understand, the data is still in the .mdb file, but I havent found any (free) tool to extract them.

Comment: 180 euros? It's daylight robbery, but I'd take the hit if your data is really worth the pain of recovery. You're wasting time and money trying other things that don't work. I trust you've learnt your lesson about backups.

Comment: @RandolphWest or better 61,335 Drachmas since he is from Greece :)

Comment: @RandolphWest As always, this "emergency tool", costs a lot. I know about backups. I keep a triple copy (in 3 different disks) of my work WHILE I work. The specific .mdb was not mine. I 'm just trying to help... :)

Comment: It costs whatever people are willing to pay for it in a "free" market economy. I still think your database owner should take the hit.

Comment: @RandolphWest The db owner would "take the hit", but (I thought I mentioned that, but then maybe I didnt), the money would have to come out of an already shrinked employ's salary. No org or co would pay for it, as it was not "their mistake" the records where deleted (either by missuse or by an internal MS Access error, one can't realy tell). Either way, the data is still there, and it feels strange to have to pay. It's like paying for the undo (OK, the undelete) function or something... :)

Comment: Data recovery costs something, whether time or money or both.

Comment: Backing up and reinstating a mdb file is super easy.  If something is important to you or you company always get regular backups.  An easy to us and cheap source is winzip.  You can create backup tasks and then schedule them.

Comment: @Linger You missed the part where I said I was not the one creating and not backing up the said .mdb file. No need for preaching to the choir about backups, nor about winzip. I keep triple copies of my work, AS I work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: According to a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3103790/1383298) and accepted answer on Stack Overflow, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Found a tool called [Access Fix Toolbox](http://www.access.fixtoolboxx.com/).  For personal use, it comes with a $27 price tag.  Slightly less steep.  There is a demo, so you can try it out.  Remember to try it off a backup of the database so if it doesn't work things don't get worse.

Comment: @dangowans Thank you for your answer. As I stated in the original question, I have already tried Access Fix Demo, wich showed the lost records, but wouldn't retrieve them unless bought. It has become considerably cheaper since then, though. My friend has already re-entered the data and recreated the .mdb.

Comment: @Acro "Access Fix Toolbox" is a separate product from "AccessFix".  Glad you're back in business.

Answer (score 0):

If you've closed or compact/repaired the database since the records have been deleted it's not happening.

When Access closes it will dump anything that is stored temporarily. When Access Compacts/Repairs all it does it copy the table contents to new tables, deletes the old table and then renames the new ones and builds the relationships.

Restore from backup

Answer (score 0):

You might be in luck if System Restore has been configured on your computer. You can right-click on the folder that contains the Access database and click `Restore Previous Versions`.  Even yet, you can view all of the shadow copies on your computer using a tool like [ShadowCopyView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shadow_copy_view.html). ShadowCopy runs every so often, so the faster you access the data the better.

If you don't have System Restore enabled, you won't see much there, but that's the only other place you could look other than a backup you have store the data on.